# formating the key words and abstract in Latex

Tags: xetex

[image: key words]

Key words and abstract are not properly aligned.

I am using Latex to write an journal article. See the attached screenshot. I want the abstract and the key words to have the same margin.
How can I adjust the indent length so that it will be aligned with the abstract. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[sumlimits,]{amsmath}

\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sectionbookmark}[1][]{%
  \bookmark[%
    level=section,%
    dest=\@currentHref,%
    #1%
  ]%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{abstract}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0.5in}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \textbf{\textit{Key words: }} #1
}

\begin{document}
\title{Notes for XYZ Series Analysis}
\author{XXYYZZ}
\date{March 31, 2020}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
This is a test. That is an abstract.  T This is a test. That is an abstract. 

\end{abstract}

\hspace{0.5in}
\keywords{probability, reliability, Monte Carlo, word.}
\section{Introduction}
This is a test. That is an abstract. This is a test.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Why don't you provide a minimal working example for users who want to help you with your issue? Best regards

Comment: Put the keywords into the abstract.

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: How can I remove the indentation for the entire abstract?

Comment: *You* defined the indent yourself by using the abstract package and its commands for left and right indentation.